# Cannot execute queries from SQL Server 2008 Management Studio

Tags: sql-server-2008

I've installed SQL Server Management Studio 2008 on my Windows XP PC.

After I connected a SQL Server on a remote machine and tried to execute ANY query from the Query window, it failed with the message:

"Unable to start T-SQL Debugging. Could not attach to SQL Server process 'on

As per the article "Configuring the Transact-SQL Debugger" 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646024.aspx 
I checked the firewall on my PC. It was disabled. But the error still occured.

My co-worker managed to execute queries from Management Studio 2008 installed on his PC by connecting the same server that I did.

How can I fix the problem? I did not want to debug queries, just to execute them.

Thanks, Lev

Comment: You are definitely pressing the red exclamation mark not the green play button? (Bit confusing if you are used to working in Visual Studio!)

Comment: customize your toolbar to exclude buttons, especially if you never going to use them

Comment: Martin, thanks for the idea. The error occurs when I press the green play button but everything works fine for the Execute (red exclamation mark) button. K Ivanov, your comment is also usefule.

Comment: Understandable, since you said "I've installed SQL Server Management Studio 2008" -- Mgmt Studio for 2005 has no green arrow next to the red execute button -- the green arrow started in 2008, and becomes a green "Debug" button in versions 2012 & 2014.  (If, like me, you found this page even though you're on 2012/2014, you might like Lynn Langit's demo ***[here on YouTube](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957368/debugging-in-sql-management-studio-2012)***, posted in answer to ***[this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957368/debugging-in-sql-management-studio-2012)***)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To execute the query without it trying to run it in debug mode press the red exclamation mark on the toolbar or hit `F5` rather than by hitting the green play button.