# Debugging in SQL Management Studio 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

I'm using Management Studio 2012 but I'm not able to debug any SQL code. After I hit the Debug button I'm not getting any green arrow on the left side and none of my SQL object are being loaded to the memory.

I'm getting this message when I move my cursor over the breakpoint I set: `The breakpoint will not currently be hit. Unable to bind SQL breakpoint at this time. Object containing the breakpoint not loaded.`

I followed a youtube video demonstrating how to debug in Studio 2012: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_jsFM_PUPgA&feature=relmfu
The guy in the video around 4:30 writes a small SQL query, puts a breakpoint in the SELECT and clicks on `Debug`. Then he will get a small green arrow on the top left corner of the editor and also his breakpoint is being hit. Mine isn't.

This is what I would like to debug:

```
declare @count int = 0
while @count <> 10
begin
   select @count
   set @count = @count + 1
end
```

It's pretty simple and the debugging should work. Of course, I would like to debug more complex stored procedures later on..

Any suggestions?

Comment: which version are you using Express or Complete ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out that I was trying to debug from a remote machine. Logging into the Server Computer and debugging locally was working.

Answer (score 5):

I made a [short video on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zDiiL_EK8Oc) showing the process to do debug a T-SQL query in SQL Server 2012 SSMS - here's the link.  If this doesn't help, it may be helpful if you post a short video of the steps you are taking and then edit your answer to include that video, then I'll take a look and try to advise from there.